# How do you access scope variables of a number of directives?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive representing a person with location attributes that change. I'll like to access all the locations together and plot them on a map using something like the angular-leaflet-directive. How can I access these variables in one place? I think I'm really close to getting it working but I don't know which scope has access to all the directives variables. Here is what I have so far?

Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title></title>

  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.0-rc.3/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.0-rc.3/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.0-rc.3/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>

</head>

<body ng-controller='MainCtrl'>

  <a href='' class='btn' ng-click='addPerson()'>Add new person</a><Hr>

  <div id='people'>
    <person lat="0.0" lng="0.0"></person>
    <person lat="0.0" lng="0.0"></person>
    <person lat="0.0" lng="0.0"></person>
  </div>
  <hr>

  <div class="map"> <!-- this will be a directive representing a map -->
      How do I access the lat and lon of each directive here? So I can plot them all on a map (which is also a directive ...)
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

App.js

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.directive('person', function ($compile, $timeout) {

    function link ($scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {     

        $scope.lat  = attrs.lat;
        $scope.lng  = attrs.lng;


        $timeout( function changePosition() {

            console.log('Changing position ...');
            $scope.lat  = Math.random()
            $scope.lng  = Math.random()

            $timeout(changePosition, 2000);
        }, 2000);
    }

    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      replace: true,
      template: "<span>Current Lat={{lat | number:2}}, Lng={{lng | number:2}}<br><br></span>",
      link : link,
      scope: {},
    }

});

app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $compile) {

    $scope.addPerson = function() {
            console.log('Adding new person');
            var lat  = Math.random()
            var lng  = Math.random()
            angular.element('#people').append($compile('<person lat="'+lat+'" lng="'+lng+'"></person>')($scope));
    }


});
```

Comment: shouldn't "people" array already be in the $scope of MainCtrl and render them with ng-repeat? adding a person would simply be a push in the array, not this $compile/append thing which you should definately get rid of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to define those variables in scope section of directive, and you can access them in link function like you use in controller.

```
app.directive('person', function ($compile, $timeout) {

function link ($scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {     

    $timeout( function changePosition() {

        console.log('Changing position ...');
        $scope.lat  = Math.random()
        $scope.lng  = Math.random()

        $timeout(changePosition, 2000);
    }, 2000);
}

return {
  restrict: 'E',
  replace: true,
  template: "<span>Current Lat={{lat | number:2}}, Lng={{lng | number:2}}<br><br></span>",
  link : link,
  scope: {
      'lat': '=',
      'long': '='
  },
}

})
```

You can get good idea of how scope variables work in directive from [what-are-the-nuances-of-scope-prototypal-prototypical-inheritance-in-angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049480/what-are-the-nuances-of-scope-prototypal-prototypical-inheritance-in-angularjs/14049482#14049482).